# Read/Write Application Settings in C#.NET project

Tags: c#, asp.net, application-settings

I need to save informations (db password) permanently in my project via an `.aspx` file. I found the Application Settings to store the password but other users can not access my values.

For example:

1. Setting `db_password` has the value `oldPassword`
2. Administrator (*User A*) changes the database password to `newPassword`. It is stored into the Applicatoin settings via: `Properties.Settings.Default["db_password"] = tb_testSettingPassword.Text;`
3. Saving: `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();`
4. Administrator (*User A*) see the changed value: `lt_testSettingPassword.Text = System.Convert.ToString(Properties.Settings.Default["db_password"]);`
5. *User B* (no administrator) accesses the page and want to get informations from the database. He needs to connect via the password that *user A* has saved but I still gets the value `oldPassword`.

How can I store the value for all users?

Answer (score 0):

Settings stored with `Properties.Settings.Default` are stored in the current users own application data folder (%USERPROFILE%\AppData under Vista and above).
If you want to have a config file easily accessible to all users you should store it at `System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)`.
That line will give you the path to the common AppData folder (C:\ProgramDAta under Win7), where all users will have read and write access.
In there you should create a folder for your application and then create your config file in that folder.

If you need help creating folders and files there are multiple questions and answers on SO that should help you out.

Comment: Is this the only way? I need to deliver the program in a few weeks and I think that the folder paths will not be the same on the new windows server..

Comment: The beauty of using environment variables is that it does not matter where it points to as long as it always points to the same location in the same environment.  
It could point to `C:\somewhere\over\the\rainbow\folder` and you would not have to care